# Return a value from assembly function to calling c++ function

Tags: c++, debugging, assembly, masm

I am trying to code the collatz problem in assembly (just for fun). I just finished the first part. I am calling the assembly code from a C++ function in a different file:

```cpp
if (((n / 2) * 2) == n) n = n / 2;
else n = 3 * n + 1;
```

```
.code
isCN proc n:dword
mov eax, n
xor edx, edx
mov ecx, 2
mov r8d, eax
div ecx
mov r9d, eax
mul ecx
cmp eax, r8d
je equal
;else
mov eax, 3
mul r8d
add eax, 1
ret


equal:
; if n is even
mov eax, r9d
ret



isCN ENDP
end
```

I am using the code like that:

```cpp
extern "C" int isCN(int n);

while (n > 1) {
    c++;
    n = isCN(n);
}
validNumbers[i] = true;
counters[i] = c;
```

But when I try to use it, the value it returns is nonsense.

When I look at the disassembly, it seems to be correctly returned from `eax`.

Is the error in the way I use the code, or in the code itself?

Comment: That's quite an inefficient way to do it. That said, it does seem to work.  What is the input for which you get bad output, and what is that? Post [mcve].

Comment: For every input. 1 returns something at 80000 ( I am not Shure as I can't access my computer until tomorrow. Also, what would be a more efficient way ( I am really new to assembly)

Comment: `((n / 2) * 2) == n` is a pretty obfuscated way to write `n % 2 == 0` or `n & 1 == 0`.

Comment: You're assembling this for Windows x64, and linking with compiler-generated code for that C function?  Have you single-stepped through some values to be sure what output you get for a given input?  Jester says they tested it.

Comment: I am assembling with compiler generated code of that cpp function. Every time I step through the code, the returned value changes each time I input the same value. One output of 1: 2071820700

Comment: Post the rest of the code you are using exactly so we can reproduce it. Also verify what the `mov eax, n` assembles to, preferably check in your debugger that `eax` is set to the proper input. Do the same for the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is inefficient but from a quick test it does seem to work. A more efficient version could be:

```
    mov eax, ecx
    shr eax, 1
    jnc done
    lea eax, [2*ecx + ecx + 1]
done:
    ret
```

(Assuming you are using windows calling convention.)

Comment: I think you're assuming a 32-bit `fastcall` convention, where the first arg is in ECX?  (Or x86-64, but there's never a reason to use 32-bit address-size with LEA.  Oh, the question is using x86-64 new registers.)  This could be  even more efficient with `lea eax, [...]` / `shr ecx, 1` / `cmovc eax, ecx`; either side of the branch already has a data dependency from input to output so branchy only shortens the critical path latency by a a few cycles (it is a slow-LEA, though, with 3 components). With CMOV it's fewer instructions so better front-end throughput even assuming a not-taken branch.

Comment: Oh, Collatz, so critical path latency probably does matter.  I should have recognized that pattern :P.  But it branches unpredictably so you want CMOV.  [Why does C++ code for testing the Collatz conjecture run faster than hand-written assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40354978) - If you were inlining it into a loop, you might do two separate LEAs to optimize for latency on Intel before Ice Lake.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the `dword n` is not correctly given to the function.

Changing the line:

```
mov eax, n
```

to:

```
mov eax, ecx
```

fixed the code.

Comment: Oh, do `n:dword` in MASM only work for stack args, not register args?  I guess it's good that it doesn't invent aliases for register names, because if you wrote `mov ecx, 5` / `mov eax, n` it would look like you were still reading the incoming `n`.  So I guess better behaviour would be to warn, but then you'd to tell it how to skip the first 4 args and it would need to know the calling convention?

Comment: Maybe it treats `n:dword` as the first stack arg; that's fairly consistent once you realize why, but confusing in cases like this when it's not what the programmer was expecting.  Except it would still have to know the calling convention so it can look for the first stack arg above the shadow space, instead of right above the return address.

Comment: Seems like another case of a "high level" assembler feature designed in a time of more primitive calling conventions that just hasn't aged well, similar to `invoke`.  IMO, if you're trying to *learn* asm, you want a what-you-see-is-what-you-get with no magic from the assembler distorting what you write or reinterpreting it.  So don't use features like that.  And since this is 2023 not 1983, normal non-performance-critical code doesn't get written by hand in asm so features for that case aren't very useful either.  TL:DR: you got tripped up by an obsolete (IMO) assembler feature.